# how to send data from android to server then from server to android

Tags: java, android

I want to build an application to send data from `Android` client to `Java` localhost server, then return the replay from server to client, how can i build server? and to send the data pelase?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. on Android: you have to set the server `IP`, so if you are working on Emulator you have to use `10.0.2.2`, If you want to try it on real device using WIFI then you have to use your PC's IP.
2. On Android:

```
URI website;
try {
    HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
    website = new URI("http://"+ IP+ ":8080/ServerName/ServletName");
    HttpPost request = new HttpPost();
    request.setHeader("Data Name", Data Value);
    request.setURI(website);
    HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
    // Response From Server
    Header[] headers = response.getAllHeaders();
    for (int i = 0; i < headers.length; i++) {
    Header h = headers[i];
    }
    } catch (URISyntaxException e) {
         e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
   }
```

1. Building Server : `Eclipse` File -> New -> Dynamic Web Project.
2. Creating Servlet: on the server, right click on `src` folder, add you package -> new servlet.
3. On server: in the method `doPost`

```
String value = request.getHeader("Data Name");
response.setHeader("Response1", "Value");
```

#### note

I show you how to send data using the headers of the response and request, you can use `inputstream` and `outstream` for huge data.

Comment: I like your answer , i am trying it

Answer (score 1):

you can create a web service on the server side and call it from android client to send and recieve data, or you write a servlet

Comment: I want to upvote you, would upvote to me because i just have 6 marks :(

Comment: I upvote you.......................

Comment: I am created webservice in ASP.NET, I want to send device ID to that webservice. Please help me.